# Using Powershell to build a list of computer model numbers in our Domain?

Tags: powershell

As the title states, I am trying to determine every computer model used in our domain.  I am new to the company, and have been placed in charge of producing a new encryption solution for all end point devices.  By knowing the computer models in our domain, I will be able to determine which machines have a TPM 1.2 chip, and which ones don't (almost 15k devices).  I do not need anything to look pretty, but I'm open for ideas.  I more or less want a list (text or csv  for sorting purposes) so I can quantify models and research.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'ML*'} | select -expand name | 
ForEach {
    If (Test-Connection $_ -count 1 -quiet)
    {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_} Select-Object -Property model | Export-Csv "c:\scripts\Models.csv"}
    Else { Add-Content -value $_ c:\scripts\not.responding.txt}
```

I know there are problems with this.  Right now I'm having trouble querying AD and passing the computer name variable only.  Because of this, the ping test fails, and everything exports to the failed text file.  The failed text file indicates that the variable includes a lot more than just the computer name.  If I can pull the variable correctly, I'm not sure if the rest would work, but I think it should.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ComputerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'ML*'} | select -expand name
foreach ($computername in $ComputerNames){
 If (Test-Connection $computername -count 1 -quiet){
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computername | Select-Object -Property model | Export-Csv "c:\scripts\Models.csv"
 }
 else{
    Add-Content -value $computername c:\scripts\not.responding.txt
 }
 }
```

there you go.

Comment: Thank you!  Works great now.  I just had to modify the export-csv line by changing it to add-content.  Otherwise it kept deleting the output of the prior sucessfull interation